# Tree implementation without using pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I found this code somewhere that is a simple implementation of a tree. Is there a reason why the `left` and `right` have to be pointers to `Node`? In other words, can you still implement a tree without `left` and `right` being pointers and just being of type `Node`? If so, could someone please provide an example

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node { 
    int data; 
    struct Node* left; 
    struct Node* right; 
  
    Node(int val) { 
        data = val;
        left = NULL; 
        right = NULL; 
    } 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct Node* root = new Node(0);
    root->left = new Node(1);
    root->right = new Node(0);
    root->right->left = new Node(1);
    root->right->right = new Node(0);
    root->right->left->left = new Node(1);
    root->right->left->right = new Node(1);

    std::cout << root->data << "\n";
}
```

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: No. Such implementation will require an infinite amount of memory for `Node`.

Comment: @MikeCAT, sorry I'm new to cpp. Why would it require an infinite amount of memory?

Comment: if every node has a left and a right, the size of the tree is infinite. It has to stop somewhere, ie some nodes dont have right/left

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 But how does making left and right pointers solve that problem?

Comment: Because pointers only require a fixed allocation of memory (typically 4 or 8 bytes each); there is no *implicit* recursion - the child nodes are only created *when needed*. The pointers can be `NULL`.

Comment: Ohh ok I think I understand. Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler example of a linked list, ie each `Node` has only one `next`:

```
struct Node {
    Node next;
};
```

C++ does not allow this, you will get an error, but lets consider for a moment there was no error. Then every `Node` contains another `Node` and that member again contains another `Node`. And that `Node` has another member `next` which is a `Node` too. This `Node` has a member `next` of type `Node`. That `Node` has another member `next` which is a `Node` too. This `Node` has a member `next` of type `Node`... ad infinitum.

Maybe you are coming from a language where objects are actually references. In C++ an object is the object. It cannot be "no object". Objects cannot be `NULL`.

Pointers on the other hand can point to an object, but they can also point nowhere. This is fine:

```
 struct Node {
     Node* next;
 };
```

Each `Node` has a member `next` that either points to a `Node` or not.

One way to see why the first is not allowed in C++ is that sizes of members must be known to the compiler. The size of a pointer is the same no matter what is the size of the object itself. However, as explained above, it is not a restriction of C++, but rather it is impossible to have something that contains itself infinite many times.

Comment: Beautiful explanation. Thank you so much.